# Lastpass VS Sxipper. which one is better at their thing?

Tags: firefox, security, passwords, browser-addons

Well, i've been using sxipper for some time now, but recently came across lastpass. I can't tell which one is more secure or has a better functionality, sxipper however seems easier to use.

Comment: Which browser, what OS?

Comment: sxipper is a firefox only plugin so, it would seem, he would be using firefox.

Answer (score 3):

My vote would go to lastpass for being cross platform and supporting multiple browsers and being able to keep the database accessibly to all of them.

The security of lastpass has been [debated](http://forums.lastpass.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=4389)

You can also see other password options [here](https://superuser.com/questions/255/how-do-you-keep-track-of-all-your-passwords)

Comment: I don't now about sxipper, but lastpass can also use two factor yubikeys which helps. They recently had a tiny amount of unexpected traffic on their network and took pretty conclusive counter measures to protect the end users, which is encouraging. It goes without saying dont use either of these systems to store any sensitive passwords, but rather the many, many low-security passwords you need everyday to live online (and even then you can bump them up a bit now you dont need to remember them).

Answer (score 2):

Lastpass is ubiquitous and cross-platform.

I believe the lastpass to be much more secure though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how LastPass dose it, but Sxipper never stored any password off site, that means that all your passwords are stored on your computer.  Only form completion schemes where stored on Sxippers server. Now I don't know what do you consider secure, but in my opinion, the most secure option is when only you and your computer know your passwords(Sxipper), not a third party server(LastPass).